# C programming - Sockets ("Server" showing "Client" name on chat)

Tags: c, windows, sockets

im still newbie in C sockets progamming, thanks to this site i learned a lot of useful stuff, but i coudnt find how to make the server show the client name in chat, i know i need to use the command: "send(SOCKET s,const char *buf,int len,int flags);" , but i dont know what im doing wrong, either wrong syntax or wrong positioning, idk, these are the codes:

(i put this "//<------" in what i think its wrong)

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windows.h> //Sleep();
#include <locale.h>

WSADATA data;
SOCKET winsock;
SOCKADDR_IN sock;
char buffer[1024];
char buffer2[1024];
char nome[50];

int bytes;
int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1),&data)==SOCKET_ERROR){
printf("Erro ao inicializar o winsock");
return 0;
}

if((winsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==SOCKET_ERROR){
printf("Erro ao criar socket");
return 0;
}

sock.sin_family=AF_INET;
sock.sin_port=htons(1234);

if(bind(winsock,(SOCKADDR*)&sock,sizeof(sock))==SOCKET_ERROR){
printf("Erro colocar utilizar a função BIND");
return 0;
}

listen(winsock,1);

while((winsock = accept(winsock,0,0))==SOCKET_ERROR){
Sleep(1);
}

printf("Cliente conectado!");

while(1){
 Sleep(1);
  memset(buffer2,0,1024);
  bytes=recv(winsock,buffer2,1024,0);

          if(bytes==-1){
          printf("Conexão perdida");
          getch();
          return 0;
          }

 memset(nome,0,50); //<------

 printf("%s:",nome);
 printf(buffer2);
 printf("Servidor: ");
 gets(buffer);
 strcat(buffer,"\r\n");
 send(winsock,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);

}
getch();
closesocket(winsock);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

WSADATA data;
SOCKET winsock;
SOCKADDR_IN sock;
char buffer[1024];
char buffer2[1024];
char nome[50];
int bytes;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    gets(nome);


    strcat(nome,"\r\n");               //<------
    send(winsock,nome,strlen(nome),0); //<------
    memset(nome,0,50);                 //<------



if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1),&data)==SOCKET_ERROR){
printf("Erro ao inicializar o winsock");
return 0;
}

if((winsock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==SOCKET_ERROR){
printf("Erro ao criar socket");
return 0;
}

sock.sin_family=AF_INET;
sock.sin_port=htons(1234);
sock.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

if(connect(winsock,(SOCKADDR*)&sock,sizeof(sock))==SOCKET_ERROR){
printf("Erro ao se conectar");
return 0;
}

printf("Conectado!\n");

while(1){
 Sleep(1);
 printf("%s:",nome);
 gets(buffer);
 strcat(buffer,"\r\n");
 send(winsock,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
 memset(buffer2,0,1024);
 bytes=recv(winsock,buffer2,1024,0);
       if(bytes==-1){
       printf("Conexão perdida");
       getch();
       return 0;
       }

 printf(buffer2);

}

getch();
closesocket(winsock);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `send()` in the beginning of the client?  At that time, your client has no opened socket(`winsock`) and not connect to the server yet.

Answer (score 1):

The steps for socket communication on the client side are

1. Create a socket by using `socket()` function.
2. (optional) Bind the socket to a local address and/or port using the `bind()` function.
3. Connect the opened socket to the server address with `connect()`.
4. Send or received data with `read()` and `write()`, or `recv()` and `send()`.

The steps for server side are

1. Create a socket by using `socket()` function.
2. Bind the socket to a local address and/or port using the `bind()` function.
3. Listen for connections with `listen()`.
4. Accept connections with `accept()`.
5. Send or received data with `read()` and `write()`, or `recv()` and `send()`.

In your code, your client calls `send()` too early.  You have not open the socket yet.

Edit:
On the server code, you should do a `memcpy()` to copy your data from `buffer2` to your `nome` array.  Please remember check array boundary.

On client code, you need to remove `memset(nome,0,50);` and move the `send()` after `printf("Conectado!\n");`.

Comment: ok thanks, but thats wasnt what i asked, the code works, the only thing i want is to server show client name

Comment: @Gouki0: the client has to send its name to the server, either in every message it sends, or at the beginning of communication before sending its first message. Then the server will know what to display on each message it receives. You are not doing that.  Otherwise, all the server can display is the client IP:Port reported by `getpeername()` or `accept()`.  You have not even created a structured protocol to define how your messages are formatted and transmitted (headers, fields lengths, character encodings, message delimiters, etc).  You really need to do that.

Comment: could u tell me how can i send from client to server the content of the char "nome" and what codes should i use ? i just want to allocate what is in the client "nome" to "nome" in server.

Comment: in client i just need this                                              "[...]printf("Conectado!\n");

    send(winsock,nome,strlen(nome),0); //<------
    
while(1){[...]" ? is the syntax correct ?

Comment: @Gouki0 From you code logic, the sequence is correct.

Comment: thanks guys, i got this, all i need to do was: in server and client add: "recv(winsock,nome,50,0);" and "send(winsock,nome,strlen(nome),0);" respectively, after socket is connected.